# Can't find a resource file containing a specific text taken from SharePoint .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

We have a site in 14 hive, specifically:

```
Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SubNew.aspx
```

Most of the labels in this page are taken from the Resources file, for example [line 150]:

```
Description="<%$Resources:wss,subnew_alerttitle_desc%>"
```

But there are some texts that somehow appear on this page, for example:

```
All changes 
New items are added 
Existing items are modified 
Items are deleted
```

and I don't know where are they taken from or how they are generated. I've tried searching the whole "14" folder with Notepad++ "Find in Files" feature but it didn't return a single match.

In the code (SubNew.aspx) the closest thing to the location where the texts are displayed is:

```
<Template_Control>
    <asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioBtnEventType" CssClass="ms-authoringcontrols" Runat="server" />
</Template_Control>
```

but I can't understand how the radio buttons are generated and where the texts are coming from.

Is there any location where I should look for a Resources file where the text might be stored in?

Is there any possibility the texts are generated on-the-fly without actually being stored in Resources file? If so, where are they generated?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The texts are hardcoded into 14/ISAPI/Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Used [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to retrieve the code.